# How do I view the number of pages of a print job in the printer queue?

Tags: printing

I can't find anything about the number of pages of a job that's in the printer queue (that's yet to be released). I've tried looking through the attributes via "View Attributes", but the number of pages is not shown on the window. Is it possible to view this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but I'd try looking at the queue through the cups interface.

- In your browser address bar enter: `http://localhost:631/printers`.
- You should see your printer in the "Queue names", click it and go to "show all jobs".
- If there are no printers you will have to add it through `http://localhost:631/admin`.